# Looping the records in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query..

```
Begin
   declare @Col int,
           @lev int,
           @Plan int

select @Col = 411
select @lev = 16
select @Plan = 780             

--Insert into baCodeLibrary(Plan_Num,Level_Num,Column_Num,Block_Num,Code_Id,Sort_Order,isactive,Added_By,DateTime_Added,Updated_By,DateTime_Updated)
Select Distinct 
    @plan,
    @lev,
    @col,
    ba_Object_Id - 5539,
    ba_Object_Id, 
    ba_OBject_Desc, 
    ba_Object_Id - 5539,
    1,
    'xyz',
    GETDATE(),
    'xyz',
    GETDATE()
from baObject 
where ba_OBject_Id > 5539 
    and ba_Object_Id < 5554

end
```

Here I have only for the `@col = 411`, but I want to loop for all the column until 489

Could any body help me out how to write the loop in this query to select all the columns from 411 to 489?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this value determined arbitrarily? Can you store these values and join to them. Looping sounds like a bad way to do this.

Comment: Please don't tag SQL Server questions with [tag:MySQL]. "MySQL" is a database platform and does not mean "my SQL-related problem."

Answer (score 2):

How about not thinking about this in terms of a loop, and instead think about it in terms of a set?

```
declare @lev int,
        @Plan int;

select @lev = 16,
       @Plan = 780;

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (489-411) Number 
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
    WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY Number
)
--Insert dbo.baCodeLibrary(...)
SELECT DISTINCT
  @plan,
  @lev,
  n.n,
  ba.ba_Object_Id - 5539,
  ba.ba_Object_Id, 
  ba.ba_Object_Desc, 
  ba.ba_Object_Id - 5539,
  1,
  'xyz',
  GETDATE(),
  'xyz',
  GETDATE()
FROM dbo.baObject AS ba CROSS JOIN n
  where ba.ba_Object_Id > 5539 
  and ba.ba_Object_Id < 5554;
```

Comment: +1 Aaron, just a side question: Is there any difference between `WITH CTE AS (Col1, Col2, ...) ()` and `WITH CTE AS ()` other than first one clearly defining list of output columns?

Comment: @Kaf no, just preference

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual looping mechanism in your query as it exists now.  You'll need to implement something like a while loop in order to get that functionality.

See:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx

It'll look something like

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 1

WHILE @counter < 10
BEGIN

-- loop logic

SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping can be performed three ways in T-SQL; a WHILE loop, a SET based operation, or a [CURSOR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

T-SQL / SQL Server are optimised for SET based operations, and they are easily the most efficient way to loop, but it all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

You may be warned away from cursors, with good reason, but they are perfectly acceptable as long as you understand what you're doing. Here's an example of a very simple, fast cursor:

```
DECLARE @myColumn VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE cTmp CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT MyColumn
FROM MyTable (nolock)

OPEN cTmp

FETCH NEXT FROM cTmp INTO @myColumn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Do something with @myColumn here
        FETCH NEXT FROM cTmp INTO @myColumn
    END
CLOSE cTmp
DEALLOCATE cTmp

GO
```

Please do not use this code without reading up on cursors first - they should only be used when SET based operations are not suitable. It depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve - cursors can be very resource hungry, and can result in locked records / tables if you're not careful with the hints you apply to them.